# Meal plan for the week

Tags: python, beginner

So I made this program, where you can add a recipe which is saved as a json and you can get a plan for your meals and a grocerylist back.

```
"""Program that help you to decide what to eat for the week
   You should start adding some Recipies and ingredience you need
   for the Recipie. If you have at least 7 of them they will be
   used to tell you what you could cook and give you a grocery list

   Keywords are add_recipe and get_meals
"""
import sys
import getopt
import json
import glob
import random



class Usage(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

def main(argv=None):
    """Takes the Keywords add_recipe and get_meals and
    calles the underlying functions.
    """
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    try:
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "hamg", ["help", "add"
                                                         "get"])

        except getopt.error as msg:
            raise Usage(msg)

        for o, args in opts:
            print(args)
            if o in ("-h", "--help"):
                print('''Valid options ase -a to add a recipe and -m
                      to get meals and -g to get meals and grocerielist
                      ''')
                return 1
            elif o in ("-a"):
                save_recipe(add_recipe())
            elif o in ("-m"):
                recipes = get_recipes()
                weekly_meals = return_shuffled_max_seven(recipes)
                print_meals(weekly_meals)
            elif o in ("-g"):
                recipes = get_recipes()
                weekly_meals = return_shuffled_max_seven(recipes)
                print_meals(weekly_meals)
                print_grocerylist(weekly_meals)
            else:
                raise Usage("No valid option")


    except Usage as err:
        print(sys.stderr, err.msg)
        print(sys.stderr, "for help use --help")
        return 2

def add_recipe():
    """ Asks the user interactivly to input a recipe name
    and the ingredience

    Returns
    -------
        A dictionary with the recipe name and the list of ingedience

        Example
        -------
            {'Applepie':['Apple','Pie']}
    """
    print("Name of the recipe\n")
    name = input("> ")
    recipe = []
    while True:
        print("Add an ingredience or finalize the recipe with 'q'")
        ingredience = input("> ")
        if ingredience in 'q':
            break
        else:
            recipe.append(ingredience)
    return {name: recipe}

def save_recipe(recipe):
    """Saves the recipe to a json file"""

    #Get the first key from the dictionary: Name of the recipe
    name = next(iter(recipe.keys()))
    with open(name+'.recipe', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(recipe, f, indent=1)

def get_recipes():
    """Gets all recipes and returns them as one list"""
    grand_list_of_recipes = []
    for recipe in glob.glob("*.recipe"):
        with open(recipe, 'r') as f:
            grand_list_of_recipes.append(json.load(f))
    return grand_list_of_recipes

def return_shuffled_max_seven(a_list):
    """ Returns 7 items from a list"""
    random.shuffle(a_list)
    return a_list[:7]

def print_meals(weekly_meals):
    """Prints a weekplan for meals"""
    week=[]
    for meal in weekly_meals:
        name = next(iter(meal.keys()))
        week.append(name)
    if len(week) < 7:
        print("You only have "+str(len(week))+" recipes")
        for i in range(7-len(week)):
            week.append('')

    print('Mondays:')
    print('    '+str(week[0])+'\n')
    print('Tuesdays:')
    print('    '+str(week[1])+'\n')
    print('Wednesday:')
    print('    '+str(week[2])+'\n')
    print('Thursday:')
    print('    '+str(week[3])+'\n')
    print('Friday:')
    print('    '+str(week[4])+'\n')
    print('Saturday:')
    print('    '+str(week[5])+'\n')
    print('Sunday:')
    print('    '+str(week[6])+'\n')

def print_grocerylist(weekly_meals):
    """Prints the grocersylist"""
    meals=[]
    for meal in weekly_meals:
        name = next(iter(meal.keys()))
        meals.append(name)

    recipe_list=[]
    for idx, meal  in enumerate(meals):
        recipe_list.append(weekly_meals[idx][meal])

    grocery_list=[]
    for sublists in recipe_list:
        grocery_list += sublists

    print("Grocery List:\n")
    grocery_list = list(set(grocery_list))
    for item in grocery_list:
        print("    * "+item+"\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your imports should, per [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), be in alphabetical order:

```
import getopt
import glob
import json
import random
import sys
```

---

Unless you have a particular reason/requirement for using `getopt`, you should strongly consider using [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) instead.

---

There doesn't seem to be much point to defining your own error, catching `getopt.error` and raising `Usage` - why not just omit the handling and allow the error from `getopt` to filter back up?

---

Rather than have a separate `.recipe` file for each recipe, why not keep them all in a master dictionary `all_recipes = {name: recipe, ...}` and `json.dump` that whole dictionary into a single file? You already return a dictionary from `add_recipe`, so you could:

```
all_recipes.update(add_recipe())
```

---

Rather than fix the name e.g.

```
def return_shuffled_max_seven(a_list)
```

make the number a parameter:

```
def return_shuffled(a_list, max_=7):
```

You could then call `return_shuffled(some_list, None)` to get all of the contents back. Also, note that it shuffles the argument list in-place then returns a new slice from that list - this is unconventional behaviour and should be clearly documented (indeed, more [docstrings](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) throughout would be helpful).

---

You have a lot of repetition on days of the week in `print_meals`, consider a simplification starting with:

```
for index, day in enumerate(['Monday', 'Tuesday', ...]):
```

---

Rather than:

```
grocery_list=[]
for sublists in recipe_list:
    grocery_list += sublists

print("Grocery List:\n")
grocery_list = list(set(grocery_list))
for item in grocery_list:
    print("    * "+item+"\n")
```

Make `grocery_list` a `set` from the start:

```
grocery_list = set()
for ingredients in recipe_list:
    grocery_list.update(ingredients)
print("Grocery List:\n")
for ingredient in grocery_list:
    print("    * {}\n".format(ingredient))
```

Note also use of `str.format` instead of concatenation.